# Where the .bst file comes in

Tags: bibtex

On page 29 of [Tame the Beast](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf), it says

"Roughly speaking, BibTEX reads three files, in the following order: The .aux file first, where it
finds the name of the style file to be used, the name of the database(s), and the list of cited entries.
The .bst file is read next, and the .bib file last."

When I compile by LaTeX and BibTeX, the files I have are `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bib`, `.blg`, `.dvi`, `.log`, `.pdf`, `.tex`. Why do I not need a `.bst` file? If I want to use a `.bst` file that I make up on my own, can I?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A `.bst` file is a bibliography style file, and it is the analogous of a class `.cls` file.  When you use BibTeX, you have a command `\bibliographystyle{xyz}`, and `\bibliography{abc}`. The information about  which `.bst` file (i.e., `xyz.bst`) is written in the `.aux` file.

There are two main options to create your own `.bst`. You have to learn the language it `.bst` files are written (and the guide you  mention "Tame the BeaST" is one  of the few resources available for them). The second alternative is to use `custom-bib`. To use it, open a terminal window (command line interface) and type `latex makebst`. Then follow the prompt. At the end you will obtain a `.bst` producing a bibliography  style corresponding to  the  way you answered to the questions in the promo of `makebst`.

Another option would be to use BibLaTeX. With BibLaTeX you can design you bibliographic style coding it in LaTeX.  See this answer [Guidelines for customising biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076/16895) for an introduction on how to modifying  and customise existing BibLaTeX style

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Guido! So I checked and found that I'm using `\bibliographystyle{plain}`. However, I don't see `plain.bst` in the same folder. Where is it located?

Comment: BibTeX styles are located in `texmf` tree (same as all other 'standard' styles and classes). It should be in `texmf/bibtex/bst/base`. The proper location depends on the operating system and TeX distribution.

Comment: Is there any command to get the specific bst file loaded or to check whether or not a .bst style file has been loaded?

Comment: "Tame the BeaST" not "Tame the best"!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm also confused about it! I just don't know the difference between .bst file and .bib, do you have any advice?