# Editing bst file to change (X) to (No. X)

Tags: bibtex

I've done my own bst file using the *makebst.tex*, which produces the following output:

[image]

That is exactly what I need except for the fact that it should place the particle for number "No." inside the brackets, i.e., **12**(No. 1) instead **12**(1). Can this be done by editing the bst file?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. See, e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85432/where-the-bst-file-comes-in

Comment: Check out the `format.number` FUNCTION in your `.bst`. You could insert something like `bbl.number` where `FUNCTION {bbl.number}{ "no." }`; peruse other `.bst` files to see this in action.