# Bibtex own Reference Style

Tags: bibtex

I just created my own reference Style with the "tex makebst" command of custom-bib.
So far so good.

I am using Max OSX 10.9.4 and Sublime as an Editor.

Where exactly do I have to save the New.bst? I am kinda lost.
I found this:
[Where the .bst file comes in](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85432/where-the-bst-file-comes-in)

and I put my file to

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/meins
```

Now I tried to call the style with
`\bibliographystyle{New}`

But I have errors:

> ./settings/99_preamble.tex:42: Package biblatex Error:
>   '\bibliographystyle' invalid. [\bibliographystyle{New}]

Seems like I dont even have that bibliographystyle I read about in all the posts

Comment: biblatex doesn't use bst-files and the `\bibliographystyle` command. biblatex style are created differently.

Comment: While you are fine tuning it the bst can can go in your current directory. Can you post a MWE so that we can see what you are doing and possibly help. @UlrikeFischer As the OP made a bst file I don't think that they are using biblatex, although the error message is a worry!

Comment: @Andrew: The error message is from biblatex so Chris is using it. I naturally don't know if he/she is doing it by purpose or due to a preamble/template he/she didn't understand.

Comment: I'm new to LaTeX and I just googled for a solution, so it seems like I found the wrong one.
Can anybody recommend a tutorial for biblatex to create now styles?

Comment: My main problem was, that my Reference List ist full of ISBN / DOI and other information, I do not want to be displayed.

Comment: Use the biblatex option `isbn=false` and `doi=false` to get rid of isbn and doi.