# How to cite part of a book

Tags: citing

I want to cite https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511710

I have written following in .bib file

```
 @article{baez2007categories,
    title={Higher gauge theory, Categories in algebra, geometry and mathematical physics (eds. A. Davydov et al)},
    author={Baez, JC and Schreiber, U},
    journal={Contemporary Mathematics},
    volume={431},
    pages={7--30},
    year={2007}
 }
```

I am expecting it to come like

> J C Baez and Urs Schreiber, Higher gauge theory, in Categories in
>   Algebra, Geometry and Mathematical Physics, eds. A. Davydov et al,
>   Contemp. Math. 431, AMS, Providence, Rhode Island, 2007, pp. 7-30

It is coming as

> JC Baez and U Schreiber. Higher gauge theory, categories in algebra, geometry and mathematical
>   physics (eds. a. davydov et al). Contemporary Mathematics, 431:7–30, 2007.

I do not see what is wrong with what I have written, Book name is coming in small letters.

Working example :

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date TeX systems
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % do you *really* need it?
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{construction}{Construction}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\textheight 9.3in 
\textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout

% metadata

\title{Something}
\author{Someone}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\cite{baez2007categories}

\bibliography{Something}
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you mention what `.bst` file you are using?

Comment: @MadyYuvi I am sorry, what does .bst file mean?

Comment: Please refer the brief reply from Guido about `.bst` file, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85432/where-the-bst-file-comes-in I came to understand from your MWE, that you are using the `plain.bst` file...

Comment: One should use the `@article` entry type only for articles published in journals. You ought to be using the `@incollection` entry type.

Comment: @Mico Oh... I do not know what is "incollection".. I will read about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cite a piece that was published (usually as a chapter) in a conference proceedings volume, it is not appropriate to use the `@article` entry type. The `@article` entry type should only ever be used for, well, articles published in scholarly journals.

I believe you should be using the `@inproceedings` (synonym: `@incollection`) entry type for the entry at hand. I've tried to backfill some useful bibliographic information not contained in your posting. (Most of this information is from the AMS's website: https://bookstore.ams.org/conm-431/.)

[image]

A side comment: If you want abbreviated rather than full first names of authors and editors, you shouldn't be using the `plain` bibliography style; instead, use a style such as `abbrv`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{baez-schreiber:2007,
  author    = "John C. Baez and Urs Schreiber",
  title     = "Higher Gauge Theory",
  pages     = "7--30",
  booktitle = "Categories in Algebra, Geometry and Mathematical Physics: 
               Conference and Workshop in Honor of Ross Street's 60th Birthday,
               July 11--16\slash July 18--21, 2005",
  editor    = "Alexei Davydov and Michael Batanin and Michael Johnson 
               and Stephen Lack and Amnon Neeman",
  year      = 2007,
  publisher = "American Mathematical Society",
  address   = "Providence RI",
  series    = "Contemporary Mathematics",
  number    = 431,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you :) :)